# Why "RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded" occurred

Tags: python, debugging

I am looking at this code challenge:

> Define a function cycle that takes in three functions `f1`, `f2`, `f3`, as arguments. cycle will return another function that should take in an integer argument n and return another function. That final function should take in an argument `x` and cycle through applying `f1`, `f2`, and `f3` to `x`, depending on what `n` was.
>
> Here's what the final function should do to `x` for a few values of `n`:
>
> - `n` = 0, return `x`
> - `n` = 1, apply `f1` to `x`, or return `f1(x)`
> - `n` = 2, apply `f1` to `x` and then `f2` to the result of that, or return `f2(f1(x))`
> - `n` = 3, apply `f1` to `x`, `f2` to the result of applying `f1`, and then `f3` to the result of applying `f2`, or `f3(f2(f1(x)))`
> - `n` = 4, start the cycle again applying `f1`, then `f2`, then `f3`, then `f1` again, or `f1(f3(f2(f1(x))))`
>   And so forth.

Below is my code, but the following error occurs for the case `add_one_then_double`:

> RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded

Could anybody help me on this? Thank you!

```
def cycle(f1, f2, f3):

    """
    >>> def add1(x):
    ...     return x + 1
    >>> def times2(x):
    ...     return x * 2
    >>> def add3(x):
    ...     return x + 3
    >>> my_cycle = cycle(add1, times2, add3)
    >>> identity = my_cycle(0)
    >>> identity(5)
    5
    >>> add_one_then_double = my_cycle(2)
    >>> add_one_then_double(1)
    4
    >>> do_all_functions = my_cycle(3)
    >>> do_all_functions(2)
    9
    >>> do_more_than_a_cycle = my_cycle(4)
    >>> do_more_than_a_cycle(2)
    10
    >>> do_two_cycles = my_cycle(6)
    >>> do_two_cycles(1)
    19
    """
    def cycle_func(n):
        i=1
        result=lambda x:x
        while i<n+1:
            if i%3==1:
                result=lambda x: f1(result(x))
            elif i%3==2:
                result=lambda x: f2(result(x))
            else:
                result=lambda x: f3(result(x))
            i=i+1
        return result

    return cycle_func
```

Comment: Learn to step through it with a debugger. It's an invaluable skill helping you to fix such errors. Try to find a video tutorial for your IDE. Also, of course, try to reduce the scope and amount of code to make it easier to find errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is statements like this one:

```
result=lambda x: f1(result(x))
```

When this assignment is executed, `result` will be assigned this new lambda function. When later it is *executed*, `result(x)` will be a reference to this same function, and thus there is an infinite recursion. Here you *intended* to have a reference to the *previous* value of `result`, but as you can see, that was lost at the moment this assignment took place.

The solution, is to not create those "little" lambda functions there, but to create one inner function that gets the value of `x`, and will then go through this logic of determining what to execute next.

Here is the corrected code:

```
def cycle(f1, f2, f3):
    def cycle_func(n):
        def inner(x):
            i = 1
            result = x
            while i < n + 1:
                if i % 3 == 1:
                    result = f1(result)
                elif i % 3 == 2:
                    result = f2(result)
                else:
                    result = f3(result)
                i = i + 1
            return result

        return inner

    return cycle_func

def add1(x):
    return x + 1

def times2(x):
    return x * 2

def add3(x):
    return x + 3

my_cycle = cycle(add1, times2, add3)
identity = my_cycle(0)
print(identity(5)) # 5
add_one_then_double = my_cycle(2)
print(add_one_then_double(1)) # 4
do_all_functions = my_cycle(3)
print(do_all_functions(2)) # 9
do_more_than_a_cycle = my_cycle(4)
print(do_more_than_a_cycle(2)) # 10
do_two_cycles = my_cycle(6)
print(do_two_cycles(1)) # 19
```

Comment: oh I got it. Thank you!